# Is there a convenient way to generate points a given distance and direction away from another point on the globe in R?

Tags: r, r-sf, coordinate-systems, wgs84

I'm trying to randomly generate a point within a 10 kilometer radius of a point on the globe in R, and cannot figure out how to in a direct way. The goal is to have an arbitrary point on the globe with coordinates given in WGS84 coordinates, pick a random direction, then a random distance 0-10km and place a new point there. My current solution works, and relies on picking a random distance using runif, then using st_buffer to create a ring of that radius, subtracting the intersection of the ring with a slightly smaller ring to approximate a circle, and then using st_sample to generate a point on the ring. This works, but is incredibly slow, and I need to perform this operation millions of times in my program, so I need to find a more efficient method if possible. The overall goal is to replicate the DHS anonymization algorithm in R on a data set.

I have set up a working means of turning the generated random distances and angles into x and y coordinates in meters that can be added to a point's coordinates to displace it the correct way, but my sample is an sf data frame using WGS84, and the coordinates are therefore not in meters.[here are some example coords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th0oI.png)

I'm not sure how to properly convert the points or translations without having issues involving the curvature of the Earth messing with the distances and angles.

Comment: Welcome to SO, PatrickGlenn! (1) Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. (2) Please don't post only images of data, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). (3) Try `geosphere::destPoint(cbind(-74.00684, 40.70878), 130, 622)` finds a location 130 degrees (southeast), 622 meters away from StackExchange HQ (roughly).

Comment: How accurate do you need to be?  If you are willing to let the Earth be a perfect sphere,  start with   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_circle   ,  then look at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector to generate the 2-D coordinates you need to establish the Spherical CIrcle of interest.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `geosphere::destPoint` to find the coordinates along some bearing (degrees) and range (meters) from a known point. For an example, the Stack Exchange office is advertised as being in NYC, so we can do

```r
stackexchange <- cbind(-74.00684444589426, 40.708763941777285)
geosphere::destPoint(p=stackexchange, b=145, d=600)
#            lon      lat
# [1,] -74.00277 40.70434
```

[image]

This is vectorized as well. For instance,

- `p` (the origin coordinates) can be a matrix of 1 or more rows, and if `b` and `d` are each length 1 then the output is the same dimensions as the `p` input, just offset;
- `b` and `d` can be length greater than 1 (same lengths), so if `p` is just 1 row (one coordinate), then it will give you multiple points from that single origin `p`;
- if all three `p`, `b`, and `d` are the same length (number rows of `p`, length of `b` and `d`), then you get independent bearings/ranges from the points.